# Why is the difference between these two infinite series equal to $\frac12$?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

A follow up on [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142629/does-the-difference-of-two-converging-infinite-series-correctly-induce-the-non-t):

Take $s \in \mathbb{C}$, $\Re s \gt 1$, and the two infinite series:

$$Z_1(s) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  (-1)^n \left( \frac12 + n \right) \left( {\frac {1}{n^{s}}}-\frac {1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right)$$

and:

$$Z_2(s) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  (-1)^n \left( {\frac {1}{n^{s}}}-\frac {1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right)$$

By rewriting the series into Dirichlet $\eta(s)$'s:

\begin{align*}
Z_1(s) &= -2 \eta(s-1) + \frac12
\\ Z_2(s) &= -2 \eta(s) + 1
\end{align*}
it follows that:

$$Z_2(s-1)=Z_1(s) + \frac12$$

The non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ $+ \frac12$, now all lie (assuming RH) on the line $\Re(s)= \frac32$.

Maybe this is trivial, but the simplicity of the relation between $Z_2$ and $Z_1$ surprised me. I wondered if the term $+\frac12$ can also be derived without using the conversion into $\eta(s)$ (e.g. 'bottom up' from the individual terms of the sums)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(*)=2Z_2(s-1)-2Z_1(s)$, then
$$(*)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^n\left(\frac{\color{red}{2n}}{n^s}-\frac{\color{red}{2n}+2}{(n+1)^s}-(\color{red}{2n}+1)\left(\frac1{n^s}-\frac1{(n+1)^s}\right)\right).
$$
The terms with $\color{red}{2n}$ in the numerator cancel each other hence one is left with
$$
(*)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^n\left(-\frac{2}{(n+1)^s}-\frac1{n^s}+\frac1{(n+1)^s}\right)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^n\left(-\frac1{(n+1)^s}-\frac1{n^s}\right).$$
Let $a_n=(-1)^n/n^s$. Since $a_n\to0$ when $n\to\infty$,
$$
(*)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=-a_1=+1.
$$

Comment: Many thanks for a very nice answer, Did. And also for improving the formatting of the post. Learning new nuances of the $\LaTeX$ language every day :-)